# Xamarin.Forms method executing twice on certain devices

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin.Forms application for Android and iOS which reads a qr code and saves it in a local sqlite database.

The app is installed on 3 devices (iPhone 4s with iOS 9.3.5, iPhone 5s with iOS 9.4 and Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge with Android 6.0). Strange thing, on the iPhone 4s the barcode method to save it in the database is called twice!

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>{
                        Navigation.PopAsync();
                        DisplayAlert("Scanned Barcode", result.Text, "OK");
                        dbHelper.SaveItem(new DbItem() { Name = result.Text });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a flag to lock the event something like:

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>{

    if(flag){
        return;
    }

    flag = true;

    Navigation.PopAsync();
    DisplayAlert("Scanned Barcode", result.Text, "OK");
    dbHelper.SaveItem(new DbItem() { Name = result.Text });
});

override OnAppearing(){
    flag = false;
}
```

Comment: You might add `flag = false;` after `dbHelper.SaveItem(new DbItem() { Name = result.Text });` to unlock it again.